# cross compile libcurl to run on ios simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, libcurl, autotools

I need to cross compile `libcurl` so that I can use its API from within an iOS app running on the Xcode iOS simulator. I have a simple app  in swift that calls out to a C driver function, which then contains some calls into libcurl. I already have the appropriate bridging headers set up so the C interoperability works, I just need to link against `libcurl` now.

Unfortunately, after days of struggling I still can't get the cross compilation of `libcurl` correct, such that my app can link against it.

Note: I am compiling on an Macbook pro (m1 pro apple silicon) with MacOS Ventura 13.4

```
Darwin XXX-MacBook-Pro.local 22.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.5.0: Mon Apr 24 20:52:24 PDT 2023; root:xnu-8796.121.2~5/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000 arm64
```

I'm configuring `curl` with this call to `./configure`:

```bash
./configure --prefix /path/to/install \
   --enable-static --disable-shared \
   --with-secure-transport 
   --host=arm64-apple-darwin \
   CFLAGS="-arch arm64 -target arm64-apple-ios-simulator -isysroot $(xcrun -sdk iphonesimulator --show-sdk-path) -miphonesimulator-version-min=16.4"

make -j
make install
```

Everything configures and builds fine, but when I drag the produced static library into my app's xcode project (which I confirmed does add `libcurl.a` as a linked library) I get the following build error in xcode:

```
In /Path/to/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-altsvc.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for macOS, file '/Path/to/libcurl.a' for architecture arm64
```

## My questions:

1. Why does xcode think this object file is built for macOS? The cross compilation options passed to `./configure` through `CFLAGS` should mean it is cross compiled to run on the iOS simulator
2. What are the bare-minimum compile options (passed directly to clang/gcc) required to cross compile **anything** such that it can be pulled into xcode and run on the iOS simulator?
3. What is the appropriate invocation to curl's `./configure` such that I can create a static library for `libcurl` and import it into my xcode project?

Comment: I xcode thinks the library is built for MacOS, that's almost surely because it is.  And I would expect that to be what `--host arm64-apple-darwin` requests, though it does not seem to be well documented what the correct triplet should be.  Or even whether libcurl support iOS at all.  The libcurl project would be the best place to seek help with building libcurl for iOS.

Comment: That lack of documentation is exactly why I asked this question. I discovered that the same behavior applies to all binaries I'm building, not just `libcurl`. I got it to work if I combine that exact object file from the command above with one built for x86_64 into a universal binary using `lipo`, but neither static library alone worked (which doesn't make any sense). `--host arm64-apple-darwin` comes straight from the curl docs, and I'm pretty sure that is the correct one for iOS (I can't find a variation that works otherwise for the host triplet)